# Create new variable based on factor levels and random selection

Tags: r, variables, random

I'm a little stuck trying to use the `sample` function for my task, which is to sample *n* random rows from each level of a factor and create a new variable based on this and the value of another variable.

A simplified example:

```
Subject = c("100","100","100","100", "100", "200", "200", "200", "200", "200")
Condition = c("Blue","Blue","Blue","Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue")
Response = rnorm(10)
df = data.frame(Subject,Condition, Response)
```

Here the goal would be to sample 3 random rows for each level of `Subject`, create a new variable, let's say `Condition.Rand` which has the randomly selected rows labeled "Red" and the remaining ones labeled with whatever value was in `Condition` -- in this case, "Blue". Thus for each `Subject`, 60% of `Condition.Rand` would be labeled "Red" and 40% labeled "Blue".

To be clear, I want *exactly* 3 random rows (or 60% of the 5 observations) labeled "Red" for Subject 100, and *exactly* 3 random rows labeled "Red" for Subject 200.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` to divide `df` into sub-groups and `sample` `"Red"` and `"Blue"` with desired probability for each sub-group.

```
set.seed(42)
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Subject), function(a)
 cbind(a,
  cond.rand = sample(c("Red","Blue"), size = nrow(a), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.6,0.4)))))
#       Subject Condition   Response cond.rand
#100.1      100      Blue -1.7813084      Blue
#100.2      100      Blue -0.1719174      Blue
#100.3      100      Blue  1.2146747       Red
#100.4      100      Blue  1.8951935      Blue
#100.5      100      Blue -0.4304691      Blue
#200.6      200      Blue -0.2572694       Red
#200.7      200      Blue -1.7631631      Blue
#200.8      200      Blue  0.4600974       Red
#200.9      200      Blue -0.6399949      Blue
#200.10     200      Blue  0.4554501      Blue
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, because sometimes it returns instances where _all_ `cond.rand` is labeled "Red" for a given subject. I want _exactly_ 3 (or 60%) random rows labeled "Red" for Subject 100, and  _exactly_ 3 random rows labeled "Red" for Subject 200.

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this with `ave` from `base R`

```
set.seed(42)
df1$cond.rand <-  with(df, ave(seq_along(Subject), Subject, FUN = function(x)
    sample(c("Red", "Blue"), size = length(x), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.6, 0.4))))
df1$cond.rand
#[1] "Blue" "Blue" "Red"  "Blue" "Blue" "Red"  "Blue" "Red"  "Blue" "Blue"
```

Comment: This has the same problem as d.b.'s suggestion. I'll edit to try to explain my task more clearly.

Comment: @amurphy, try `with(df, ave(seq_along(Subject), Subject, FUN = function(x)
    sample(c(rep('Red', ceiling(length(x)*0.6)), rep('Blue', length(x) - ceiling(length(x)*0.6))))))`

Comment: @d.b Thank you very much, that does it!